# Mobile web displaying extra whitespace compared to desktop

Tags: html, iphone, css, ipad

It seems when I visit my website through mobile device (iPhone and my iPad), there's a white space, or margin sitting on the right hand side of the page. I think it has something to do with the footer being outside the pageWrapper. Here's my website http://thebrlab.com/q3030/index.html

Comment: You'll have to show us the code you think is causing the problem and what you have already tried to fix it.

Comment: It looks like you have a number of elements that have widths wider than the page wrapper. The header, nav and footer all seem to overflow. The solution to this is to change them so that they will always fit inside, using percentage based widths. The exact answer to this depends on what exactly you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use fixed width if you want your website to look good on mobile devices. Try using percentage width or [`media queries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Tell use exactly what you want and we will be able to help you.

Comment: I want to keep content contained within 992px width inside the pageWrapper, but I want my footer to extend

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your `.slider` is wider than your `wrapper`. Try making the wrapper as big as the slider see if that works.